# "During" when we talk about a very short period of time

Tags: word-choice

Here is the passage:

> Don't edit or create CSV files with Calc.
>
> Calc cannot edit CSV files directly: when you open an existing CSV file, it converts it to OTS; when you save it, it converts it back to CSV. During these conversions - under some circumstances - data loss happens.

At my opinion, the word "during" isn't a good choice here. It creates a false impression that conversions takes a lot of time. It's not so; actually, conversions takes about a second or less.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/moments-and-short-periods-of-time) these are the synonyms for "a very short period of time"

> moment
>
> > (noun) a very short period of time
>
> instant
>
> > (noun)an extremely short period of time, that ends almost immediately
>
> split second
>
> > (noun) an extremely small amount of time

Now to answer the question, I'd have to say "during" is a good enough word to use here however, your intention is to implicitly mention that these conversions take place in an incredibly short amount of time.

There are a couple of ways to do that:

> During these conversions, **which happen in an instant** - under some circumstances data loss happens.

I've used a relative clause to convey that information. You could use other words as well, for instance, **in a split second**, or **in an incredibly short amount of time**.

> during these **split-second** conversions- under some circumstances data loss happens.

you could use an adjective as well

> **in the split second these conversions happen** - under some circumstances data loss happens.

you could omit during altogether. ([Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/in+the+split+second))

was this helpful?

Comment: What you think about "On these conversions"?

Comment: It sounds fine to me, however, I guess it doesn't convey the fact that the said conversions happen in an extremely short amount of time, which is what you want to convey right?

Comment: May be. My English is not so good to answer your question for sure. The variations you have posted are very precision, but I'm looking for a something that will sound more naturally.